# Eclipse connecting errors

Tags: eclipse, networking, ide, broken-links

I'm new to using Eclipse and my experiance with it so far has been shocking. It wouldnt even install from the Exe provided on the site... Every time it tries to connect for an update or a plugin I want to install it just throws an error saying it can't connect to the site or theres an error authenticating or theres an error reading signed content. Is there something ive missed while searching the internet to resolve these issues...

I have already tried disabling firewall, disabling antivirus, setting 'Active Provider' under network connections to Manual and the default of Native, Deleting the artifacts.xml file, deleting cache.

Just as an example of the error I have included an error I've just made it create by reloading Oxygen in Available Software Sites of the settings:

```
Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen.
Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen.
Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen/201712201001.
Input is not in the XZ format
```

Also when Installing WindowBuilder from this URL http://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/WB/integration/4.7/ which is clearly working:

```
Unknown Host: http://http/download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/WB/integration/4.7/content.xml
Unknown Host: http://http/download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/WB/integration/4.7/content.xml
http
```

Comment: For WindowBuilder it looks you are using the wrong URL: `http://http/download`... instead of `http://download`... Yesterday Oxygen.2 has been released (updated site ...`/201712201001`). Maybe the Eclipse download servers were overloaded (see http://status.eclipse.org/). Please retry again. If your problem still exists, please use more technical terms to describe it (e. g. I have no idea what do you mean by _"my experiance with it so far has been shocking"_ or _"the Exe provided on the site"_?).

Comment: I hadnt noticed the HTTP:// and this has resolved the WindowBuilder issue however I meant I couldnt install using the .exe installer from eclipse. The official download for the software is an .exe.

Comment: Obvious you are using the Eclipse Installer on Windows. If [deleting `%USERPROFILE%\.p2\org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository\cache` and `%USERPROFILE%\.eclipse\org.eclipse.oomph.p2\cache`](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=518849#c5) does not fix your problem, [use directly a package](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/) instead of the Eclipse Installer.

Comment: I have done this however it wont connect to the servers to download plugins/ patches and suchlike

Comment: Did you both, retry Eclipse Installer after deleting p2 cache and using directly a package (Eclipse Installer is not required to update Eclipse or to install plug-ins)?